# Should I convert mysql to UTF-8 if only using english? If mysql and php are UTF-8 what php code needs to be changed?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

The encoding of text files in my PHP project were inconsistent. So I decided to make everything UTF-8.

At this time I plan to limit characters to English. Should I convert my Mysql database to UTF-8 or can I postpone it until I need more than English?

It appears to me that if my database is UTF-8 that I will need to use mb_(multi byte) prefexed functions, example mb_strpos and use the /u option on my regular expresions. Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not lose anything with ASCII versus UTF-8, since all characters in ASCII have the same representation in UTF-8.

TL;DR: Go for it.